# Which one is more natural to say, "various", or "vary" in the context of the sentences given below?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

1. The shapes and sizes of dinosaurs were greatly various.
2. Dinosaurs came in amazingly different sizes and shapes.
3. Dinosaurs varied in size and shape.

And are there any differences in nuance and usage among the three sentences?

Plz, Feel free to just provide example sentences.

Comment: _Varied greatly_ would be better in (1). _Various_ is usually used to precede a noun - _various sizes_.

Answer (score 0):

**Vary** is a verb.  In English, we speak of two kinds of verbs:

- Doing:  it does something.  In this case it *changes* something (vary)
- Being:  It is something (describes a state of being)

So, you would use 'vary' to talk about what things (nouns) do to each other:  e.g. the dinosaurs *vary* in size and shape.

**Various** is an adjective.  Adjectives change the meaning of the nouns they are connected to.  So, one could say that there were dinosaurs in the desert.  But when we say that there were *various* dinosaurs in the desert, we are changing the noun, letting the reader know that there are a whole lot of dinosaurs.

Comment: That does not directly address the OP's question about the difference in meaning and usage between their example sentences.

Comment: Transitive _vary_ may be about what things do to each other (eg _They varied the lighting for the different moods_), but your example, as in the original post, uses **intransitive** vary. It is hard to see how this is about anything doing something to something. Actually your division of "doing" vs "being" verbs is oversimplified, and doesn't work.